# How to Block a specific [Query String] Url via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, block

I'm very confused right now, I don't know how to block a specific QUERY STRING url via .htaccess file, well actually I want to block this type of url :

```
test.php?q=RANDOMTEXT=&tl=The%20path%20ends
```

If anyone knows how to solve this issue please let me know and thank you in advance (y)

Comment: You’ll need a RewriteCond for matching the query string and then a following RewriteRule that just blocks access via [F] flag. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Actually I'm totally n00b! :(

Comment: Then change that by reading docs & trying stuff.